# ¿Cómo puedo guardar los valores es un vector?

Tags: java, array, eclipse

Estoy empezando en programación con java y me piden **meter los valores de una apuesta en un vector.**

He intentado hacerlo pero me da siempre error.

Todavía no me han explicado muy bien el funcionamiento de vectores en java, asi que no se exactamente por donde empezar a mirar para arreglarlo.

Este es el programa entero, la zona en la que empiezan los problemas están al final. Aunque indico cuando empiezan

```
public class Sesion_04 {

    final static Scanner TECLADO = new Scanner(System.in);
    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // DATOS
        final double PRECIOAPUESTA = 1.2;
        final double PRECIO_MULTIPLE = PRECIOAPUESTA * 7;
        final double DESCUENTO = 0.05;
        final byte NUMEROS_SIMPLE = 6;
        final byte NUMEROS_MULTIPLE = 7;

        int numApuestas, tipoApuesta, i=0;
        double precioBoleto;
        byte valor;
        byte numValores;

        precioBoleto = 0;

        System.out.println("¿Cuántas apuestas quiere realizar? (1/2/3)");
        numApuestas = TECLADO.nextInt();

        // control de datos incorrectos
        while (numApuestas < 1 || numApuestas > 3) {
            System.out.println("Debe introducir un valor entre 1 y 3. Inténtelo de nuevo.\\n¿Cuántas apuestas quiere realizar? (1/2/3)");
            numApuestas = TECLADO.nextInt();
        }
        for (int apuestas = 1; apuestas <= numApuestas; apuestas++) {

            System.out.println("Introduzca apuesta número " + apuestas + ". Si desea que sea simple, introduzca 0; si no, introduzca 1");
            tipoApuesta = TECLADO.nextInt();

            // control de datos incorrectos
            while (tipoApuesta != 0 && tipoApuesta != 1) {
                System.out.println("Debe introducir el valor 0 o el valor 1. Inténtelo de nuevo.\nSi desea que sea simple, introduzca 0; si no, introduzca 1");
                tipoApuesta = TECLADO.nextInt();
            }

            // Determinar precio y numero de valores a leer en funcion de tipo de apuesta
            if (tipoApuesta == 0) {
                precioBoleto = precioBoleto + PRECIOAPUESTA;
                numValores = NUMEROS_SIMPLE;
            } else {
                precioBoleto = precioBoleto + PRECIO_MULTIPLE;
                numValores = NUMEROS_MULTIPLE;
            }


            

            // el problema empieza a darse aquí
            int[] APUESTA = new int[numValores];
            // lectura de los valores apostados
            for (byte v = 1; v <= numValores; v++) {
                System.out.print("Introduzca valor número " + v + ". Intervalo: [1..49]");
                valor = TECLADO.nextByte(); //necesito añadir estos valores que yo introduzca en un vector

                for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
                    APUESTA[i] = valor;
                }
                while (valor < 1 || valor > 49) {
                    System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, inténtelo de nuevo. Recuerde que debe estar entre el 1 y el 49.");
                    System.out.print("Introduzca valor número " + v + "...");
                    valor = TECLADO.nextByte();
                    for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
                        APUESTA[i] = valor;
                    }
                }
            }
        System.out.print("Introduzca reintegro. Intervalo: [0..9]");
        valor = TECLADO.nextByte();
        while (valor < 0 || valor > 9) {
            System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, inténtelo de nuevo. Recuerde que debe estar entre el 0 y el 9.");
            valor = TECLADO.nextByte();
        }

        if (numApuestas == 3)
            precioBoleto = precioBoleto * (1 - DESCUENTO);

        System.out.println("El precio del boleto adquirido es de " + precioBoleto + " euros. ¡SUERTE!");
        
System.out.println(APUESTA[i]); //en esta parte me da un error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6'

    }// fin del main
    }
}// fin del programa
```

No entiendo bien lo que puede pasar, asi que agradecería cualquier ayuda.
He intentado de otros modos y he debugeado el programa, pero sigo sin comprender como solucionarlo.

Comment: Agrega el resto del código e indica en que parte se produce el comportamiento no deseado.

Comment: @Lobos Ya hice el cambio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se da porque la variable `i` es global y su valor ya fue modificado, específicamente aquí:

```
for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
      APUESTA[i] = valor;
}
```

Después de terminar el `for` anterior, el valor de `i` es igual a la longitud de `APUESTA`.

Entonces al ejecutar el código:

```
System.out.println(APUESTA[i]); //en esta parte me da un error 'Exception in thread "main"
```

Se produce el error porque `i` debe tener un valor máximo de `APUESTA.length - 1`

No sé cual sea la función del código anterior pero si se desea imprimir los valores del arreglo `APUESTA` se puede reiniciar de nuevo la variable `i` y usarla en un `for`:

```
for ( i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(APUESTA[i]);
 }
```

---

Con respecto a guardar los datos en el vector te agrego el código con las correcciones, comenté dos `for` que no deben estar ahí y agregué el código correcto para insertar los valores:

```
// lectura de los valores apostados
for (byte v = 1; v <= numValores; v++) {
    System.out.print("Introduzca valor número " + v + ". Intervalo: [1..49]");
    valor = TECLADO.nextByte(); //necesito añadir estos valores que yo introduzca en un vector


    //  for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
    //  APUESTA[i] = valor;
    //  }
    while (valor < 1 || valor > 49) {
        System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, inténtelo de nuevo. Recuerde que debe estar entre el 1 y el 49.");
        System.out.print("Introduzca valor número " + v + "...");
        valor = TECLADO.nextByte();
        //  for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
        //  APUESTA[i] = valor;
        //   }
    }

    // agregar el valor en la posición i hasta que se haya validado que sea
    // correcto
    APUESTA[i] = valor;
    // después de agregarlo incrementar el valor de i
    i++;
}
```

---

**Código completo corregido**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {

    final static Scanner TECLADO = new Scanner(System.in);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // DATOS
        final double PRECIOAPUESTA = 1.2;
        final double PRECIO_MULTIPLE = PRECIOAPUESTA * 7;
        final double DESCUENTO = 0.05;
        final byte NUMEROS_SIMPLE = 6;
        final byte NUMEROS_MULTIPLE = 7;

        int numApuestas, tipoApuesta, i = 0;
        double precioBoleto;
        byte valor;
        byte numValores;

        precioBoleto = 0;

        System.out.println("¿Cuántas apuestas quiere realizar? (1/2/3)");
        numApuestas = TECLADO.nextInt();

        // control de datos incorrectos
        while (numApuestas < 1 || numApuestas > 3) {
            System.out.println("Debe introducir un valor entre 1 y 3. Inténtelo de nuevo.\\n¿Cuántas apuestas quiere realizar? (1/2/3)");
            numApuestas = TECLADO.nextInt();
        }
        for (int apuestas = 1; apuestas <= numApuestas; apuestas++) {

            System.out.println("Introduzca apuesta número " + apuestas + ". Si desea que sea simple, introduzca 0; si no, introduzca 1");
            tipoApuesta = TECLADO.nextInt();

            // control de datos incorrectos
            while (tipoApuesta != 0 && tipoApuesta != 1) {
                System.out.println("Debe introducir el valor 0 o el valor 1. Inténtelo de nuevo.\nSi desea que sea simple, introduzca 0; si no, introduzca 1");
                tipoApuesta = TECLADO.nextInt();
            }

            // Determinar precio y numero de valores a leer en funcion de tipo de apuesta
            if (tipoApuesta == 0) {
                precioBoleto = precioBoleto + PRECIOAPUESTA;
                numValores = NUMEROS_SIMPLE;
            } else {
                precioBoleto = precioBoleto + PRECIO_MULTIPLE;
                numValores = NUMEROS_MULTIPLE;
            }


            // el problema empieza a darse aquí
            int[] APUESTA = new int[numValores];
            // lectura de los valores apostados
            for (byte v = 1; v <= numValores; v++) {
                System.out.print("Introduzca valor número " + v + ". Intervalo: [1..49]");
                valor = TECLADO.nextByte(); //necesito añadir estos valores que yo introduzca en un vector


                //    for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
                //        APUESTA[i] = valor;
                //    }
                while (valor < 1 || valor > 49) {
                    System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, inténtelo de nuevo. Recuerde que debe estar entre el 1 y el 49.");
                    System.out.print("Introduzca valor número " + v + "...");
                    valor = TECLADO.nextByte();
                    //    for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
                    //        APUESTA[i] = valor;
                    //    }
                }

                // agregar el valor en la posición i hasta que se haya validado que sea
                // correcto
                APUESTA[i] = valor;
                // después de agregarlo incrementar el valor de i
                i++;
            }
            System.out.print("Introduzca reintegro. Intervalo: [0..9]");
            valor = TECLADO.nextByte();
            while (valor < 0 || valor > 9) {
                System.out.println("Valor incorrecto, inténtelo de nuevo. Recuerde que debe estar entre el 0 y el 9.");
                valor = TECLADO.nextByte();
            }

            if (numApuestas == 3)
                precioBoleto = precioBoleto * (1 - DESCUENTO);

            System.out.println("El precio del boleto adquirido es de " + precioBoleto + " euros. ¡SUERTE!");

            //System.out.println(APUESTA[i]); //en esta parte me da un error 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 6 out of bounds for length 6'

            for (i = 0; i < APUESTA.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(APUESTA[i]);
            }
        } // fin del main
    }
} // fin del programa
```

Comment: muchísimas gracias, me ha servido perfectamente y además he entendido todo. Gracias, de verdad